Analytical solution of a coupled non-linear pde?
Hi, I want to find the solution to this non-linearly coupled PDE:
$\partial_t(L_x) = - \partial_r(L_x v^r) - \Omega L_y$;
$\partial_t(L_y) = - \partial_r(L_y v^r) + \Omega L_x$
Here,

$L_x(r,t)$ and $L_y(r,t)$ are both functions of space and time.
$v^r$ is the radial velocity, which you can assume as a function of
space only, like $v^r = -k/\sqrt{r}$, where $k$ is a constant.
$\Omega$ is also a function of space only, i.e. $\Omega = 2a/r^3$,
where $a$ is a constant.

The initial conditions are $L_x(r,0) = f(r)$, and $L_y(r,0) = 0$. Here, $f(r)$ is an arbitrary function.
BCs are: $L_x(0,t) = L_y(0,t) = 0$, and $L_x(r_{max},t) = f(r_{max}); L_y(r_{max},t) = 0$.
Honestly, I am okay with finding the general solution (without ICs and BCs, and leaving the solutions with constants of integration.)
My attempt in solving the equation using separation of variables:

Assumed $L_x = X(r) T_x(t)$; and $L_y = Y(r) T_y(t)$
Above assumptions gave (after doing the usual separation of variables steps):

$\frac{1}{T_x(t)} \frac{d T_x(t)}{dt} = \frac{k}{\sqrt{r}} \frac{1}{X(r)} \frac{d X(r)}{dr} - \frac{k}{2r^{3/2}} - \frac{2a}{r^3} \frac{Y(r)}{X(r)} \frac{T_y(t)}{T_x(t)}$,
$\frac{1}{T_y(t)} \frac{d T_y(t)}{dt} = \frac{k}{\sqrt{r}} \frac{1}{Y(r)} \frac{d Y(r)}{dr} - \frac{k}{2r^{3/2}} + \frac{2a}{r^3} \frac{X(r)}{Y(r)} \frac{T_x(t)}{T_y(t)}$.

Assumed exponential time dependence, $( T_x(t) = e^{\lambda_x t})$ and $( T_y(t) = e^{\lambda_y t})$:

$\lambda_x = \frac{k}{\sqrt{r}} \frac{1}{X(r)} \frac{d X(r)}{dr} - \frac{k}{2r^{3/2}} - \frac{2a}{r^3} \frac{Y(r)}{X(r)} e^{(\lambda_y - \lambda_x) t}$,
$\lambda_y = \frac{k}{\sqrt{r}} \frac{1}{Y(r)} \frac{d Y(r)}{dr} - \frac{k}{2r^{3/2}} + \frac{2a}{r^3} \frac{X(r)}{Y(r)} e^{(\lambda_x - \lambda_y) t}$.

Now, if I assume that $\lambda_x = \lambda_y$, then, only above equations can be separated completely into spatial and time component, and hence became ODEs. However, that's a limiting case. And, I don't want to assume $\lambda_x = \lambda_y$, because in my simulations, I see that their time evolution are different.

I was wondering if anyone can give me directions on how to solve/simplify it, either using separation of variables, or eigenfunction decomposition, or Laplace transform or Fourier analysis?
Connection to the Euler top problem (it may give you ideas, not sure!)
So, the above equations has a resemblance to an euler top http://www-f1.ijs.si/~ramsak/KlasMeh/three.pdf, without radial flux term $-\partial_r(L_x v^r)$. Generally, in euler top, you have all three equations for three cartesian components of angular momentum, where you assume $L_i = I \omega_i$, where $I$ is inertia of the rigid body, and $\omega_i$ is angular velocity.
Landau and Lifshitz found the solution of above equations without radial flux term $-\partial_r(L_x v^r)$, but with two available constraints: conservation of angular momentum and energy. See (Eq 38 to 41) https://doi.org/10.1093/mnras/stv1818. This paper has also advanced the solution to one step further with external torque (see Appendix A2). However, their equation has no space dependency.
I'll greatly appreciate any help/suggestions.

First, a remark: since $v^r$ and $\Omega$ do not depend on $L_x$ and $L_y$, the PDEs are linear. Second: they can be combined into a single PDE for the complex function $L:=L_x+iL_y$. Indeed, multiplying the second PDE by $i$ and adding it to the first, we get
$$
\partial_t(L_x+iL_y)=-\partial_r((L_x+iL_y)v^r)+i\Omega (L_x+iL_y), \tag{1}
$$
or
$$
\partial_tL+v\partial_rL=F(r)L, \tag{2}
$$
where $v:=v^r$ and $F(r):=-\partial_rv^r+i\Omega$.
Equation $(2)$ can be solved with the method of characteristics. The corresponding Lagrange-Charpit equations are
$$
\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dr}{v}=\frac{dL}{FL}. \tag{3}
$$
The solution to $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dr}{v}$ is
$$
t-\int_{r_0}^r\frac{ds}{v(s)}=C_1, \tag{4}
$$
and the solution to $\frac{dr}{v}=\frac{dL}{FL}$ is
$$
L=C_2\exp\left(\int_{r_0}^r\frac{F(s)}{v(s)}\,ds\right). \tag{5}
$$
Combining $(4)$ and $(5)$, we can write the general solution to Eq. $(2)$ as
$$
L(r,t)=\phi\!\left(t-\int_{r_0}^r\frac{ds}{v(s)}\right)\exp\left(\int_{r_0}^r\frac{F(s)}{v(s)}\,ds\right), \tag{6}
$$
where $\phi(\cdot)$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. You can use the initial condition $L(r,0)=L_x(r,0)+iL_y(r,0)=f(r)$ to determine $\phi$.

Since $F(s)=v'(s)+i\Omega(s)$ it seems like we could further express the exponential factor in (6) as $$\frac{v(r_0)}{v(r)}\exp\left(i\int_{r_0}^r \frac{\Omega(s)}{v(s)}ds\right).$$ This makes the role of $\Omega$ a bit more explicit.

@Gonçalo
Would it be possible to determine the solution if you add an extra torque term on the right, like $\partial_r(f(r,t))$ to $L_x$ equation, and $\partial_r(g(r,t))$ to $L_y$ equation?
Also, thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate it.

@Semiclassical,I would love if you can also pitch in to my above comment. Also, thank you for your insightful comment.

The answer is yes if $f$ and $g$ do not depend on $t$.

@Gonçalo, but what if they depend on $t$? Given your knowledge on pdes, do you know any method which can lead to a possible analytical solution?

No, I don't. (But this is a statement about my ignorance, not about the existence or not of an analytical solution.)

Okay! Thanks for all your help :)
